# Passing Data between APIs and Database with React

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, react-fullstack

I am creating a project but very new to React and async programming. I am using React to display users email via an API.

I can get all the email data via ComponentDidMount calls to the API. It displays them correctly and I can get subject,body etc. Now, I need to send the body of the currently selected email via a button to my back-end side, do some work with it (compare strings to database etc) and then fetch back the result and display it in a div. What would be the best way to go about it?

I couldn't find any good answers to this from google.

Should I have gotten emails and done all that work all server side first somehow before fetching both the body and the result along with it with React? Or is there a way I can send the current body string out to my controller, do the work and then get the result back all in async?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can try both the approaches and see which suits your purpose more. Your question in its current form is too wide and will only solicit opinions. Please have a look at how to formulate the question better: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this question is too vague to answer but I know what you're coming from and I want to give you some ideas about the general structure of a React-related project:

- The backend side should be designed to Restful Api Endpoints.
- Use Redux to manage frontend (react) application's state.
- Use Redux-thunk (or Redux-saga) to manage side-effects (call api)
- In `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`, use Redux `dispatch` to dispatch an action to Redux then use Redux-thunk (or Redux-saga) to call api and update application's state.
- The component which is [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) to application's state will be updated based on state's changes.

It's long way to go but hey, that's what all of us have to go through. Good luck!

PS: If any terms are not familiar with you, do some `google-ings`.